Jackson unrecognised field
I'm trying to deserialize following xml
<fightrules>
    <fightrule id="1" owner="player" name="Переопределение разрешения открывать огонь #1"/>
    <fightrule id="2" owner="player" name="Ксеноны">
        <setting faction="xenon" civilian="engage"/>
    </fightrule>
</fightrules>

And using such definition
@Data
public class Fightrules {
    public List<Fightrule> fightrule;

    @Data
    @JsonAutoDetect
    public static class Fightrule {
        public int id;
        public String owner;
        public String name;
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        public List<Setting> setting;
    }
}


@Data
public class Setting {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String faction;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String civilian;
}

However I get an exception
Unrecognized field "faction" (class Fightrules$Fightrule), not marked as ignorable
Seems like Jackson doesn't see nested object list and tries to serialize it to Fightrules object.
I've tried to use annotations that helps Jackson resolving this kind of situation but none of them fitted. But I suppose there should be workaround. Maybe the problem in structure of xml because Setting object is optional
When I tried to serialize filled Fightrules instance to xml I got this structure of xml:
<Fightrules>
    <fightrule>
        <fightrule id="2" owner="player" name="Ксеноны">
            <setting>
                <setting faction="xenon" civilian="engage"/></setting>
        </fightrule>
        <fightrule id="1" owner="player" name="Переопределение разрешения открывать огонь #1"/></fightrule>
</Fightrules>


Strange... I wonder what would happen if you try to deserialize a plain <setting faction="xenon" civilian="engage"/>?

I've tried that and Settings object initialized without any problem

Then the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper is suspicious. Have you tried serializing a Java Fightrules class to see what is the format of the XML Jackson produces?

I can't deserialize  it because of the exception thrown. Removing annotation didn't fix anything

@BANTYC what Nikos was asking is to serialize a document containing only <setting .../> to a Setting instance, without using the fight rules.

@RobSpoor, as I mentioned it, I've tried and had no issues

@NikosParaskevopoulos. Sorry I didn't read your message. I've deserialized it and got result as it should be: https://pastebin.com/imNSn4Eq

The "F" in the outer <Fightrules> is capital in the serialized, while lower-case in the question; might be a spelling or unimportant. What is important is the <setting> wrapper element around the settings! This is what I expected to see - Jackson is not picking up the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false). Next suspect: Lombok. Can you please remove the Lombok @Data and try again? Experiment with placing the annotation on the field or on the getter. By the way, please edit the question with your new findings and include the XML from the comment as text, not image!

Also, the serialized has fightrule (singular) for the list element, the XML that cannot be serialized has fightrules (plural). Note that the field is named singular in the class, even though it describes a collection, so TBH I would rename the field in the class to be fightrules (plural!).

@NikosParaskevopoulos, I've updated question with xml serialization result. I also removed Data annotation and tried that way and had the same result. Need to mention that I also tried to deserialize xml without class definition and it returned correct structure

@knittl, thanks for advice I consider doing it after fixing current problem

The names not matching is (part of) your current problem

@knittl this fixed my problem. Many thanks
